# Get parent of the parent of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent

I have searched and tried many things to do this such as `closest()` and `parents()` and `parent()` and `find()` But i couldnt make it to work at all .

I have this html

```
<div  class='message_holder area2 user45 chatid32'>
    <a class='avatar' title='jhon'>
       <img height='28px' width = '28px' src="link to image" />
    </a>
 <div class='flag_holder'>
    <div class='edited  png32'></div>
    <div class='  png32'></div>
 </div>
 <div class='message user_chat'> hghgghgh</div>
 <div class='like_holder'>
    <div class='chattime'>02-12 22:16</div>
    <div class='likepng'></div>
    <div class='likescore'>5</div>
    <div class='unlikescore'>0</div>
    <div class='unlikepng'></div>
    <div class="like">
        <div class="editpng"></div>
        <div class="deletepng"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So what i want is when i click on on div class `deletepng` i want to remove the two divs `unlikepng` and `likepng` .

this js

```
 $(document).on ("click", ".deletepng", function () {
      $this = $(this);
     //alert( $this.closest(".like").html());  I could just make this to work
     // alert( $this.parents(".like_holder").html());  wont work
     // alert( $this.closest(".like_holder").html());  wont work
     // alert( $this.parent().parent().html());  wont work
     // alert( $this.closest(".like_holder").find(".like_holder").html()); wont work
 });
```

I just wonder why they dont work those my trying . Where  it can be my mistake ?

EDIT:

i dont know  if this have a role or not , i have what i tried inside Dialog box like that

```js
 $(document).on ("click", ".deletepng", function () { 
 $this = $(this);
 $('<div>' + c_delete + '</div>').dialog({
  resizable: false,
  buttons: {
    "Yes": function() {
      chat_text_h.html('<div class="removed"> Removed</div>'); // do something here
      $(this).dialog("close");

      //alert( $this.closest(".like").html());  I could just make this to work
      // alert( $this.parents(".like_holder").html());  wont work
      // alert( $this.closest(".like_holder").html());  wont work
      // alert( $this.parent().parent().html());  wont work
      // alert( $this.closest(".like_holder").find(".like_holder").html()); wont work
    }
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Really? You want to get your image form box with variable `this`? You can't do this. Do you have ID of `message_holder` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `closest` then use the second argument as the context.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".deletepng", function() {
  var $holder = $(this).closest('.like_holder');
  $('.likepng, .unlikepng', $holder).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='message_holder area2 user45 chatid32'>
  <a class='avatar' title='jhon'>
    <img height='28px' width='28px' src="link to image" />
  </a>
  <div class='flag_holder'>
    <div class='edited  png32'></div>
    <div class='  png32'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='message user_chat'>hghgghgh</div>
  <div class='like_holder'>
    <div class='chattime'>02-12 22:16</div>
    <div class='likepng'>like</div>
    <div class='likescore'>5</div>
    <div class='unlikescore'>0</div>
    <div class='unlikepng'>unlike</div>
    <div class="like">
      <div class="editpng"></div>
      <div class="deletepng">delete</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Since your update, you need to set a global variable to remember `$this` or the container/holder. try this:-

```js
var $holder;

$(document).on("click", ".deletepng", function() {

  $holder = $(this).closest('.like_holder');

  $('<div>' + c_delete + '</div>').dialog({
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
        chat_text_h.html('<div class="removed"> Removed</div>');
        $(this).dialog("close");

        $('.likepng, .unlikepng', $holder).remove();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: even in your snippet didnt rmove the like and unlike div

Comment: Now it works in your edit :) , hahaha you are genius :) . thanks so much . please just make little explanation so i can learn something new from you now with that :) . i should define it before dialog right ?

Answer (score 1):

`$this.closest(".like").html();` => this will return HTML of parent div, where delete button is. Not removing the element

`$this.parents(".like_holder").html()` => this will return `html` of `div.message_holder`. Not removing the element.

`$this.closest(".like_holder").html()` => this will return `html` of `div.like_holder`
`$this.parent().parent().html();` close enogh, but still far => `html` of `div.like_holder`
`$this.closest(".like_holder").find(".like_holder").html();` return null => no child element with class `like_holder` in `div.like_holder`.

Kind of example

```js
$(document).on ("click", ".deletepng", function () {
      var $parent = $(this).parent().parent();
       $parent.find('.likepng').remove();
       $parent.find('.unlikepng').remove();
     
 });
```

```css
.deletepng{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class='message_holder area2 user45 chatid32'>
    <a class='avatar' title='jhon'>
       <img height='28px' width = '28px' src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" />
    </a>
 <div class='flag_holder'>
    <div class='edited  png32'></div>
    <div class='  png32'></div>
 </div>
 <div class='message user_chat'> hghgghgh</div>
 <div class='like_holder'>
    <div class='chattime'>02-12 22:16</div>
    <div class='likepng'> like me</div>
    <div class='likescore'>5</div>
    <div class='unlikescore'>0</div>
    <div class='unlikepng'> unlike me</div>
    <div class="like">
        <div class="editpng"></div>
        <div class="deletepng">delete button</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to make it from dialog box, or other things - you can't use `this` variable. This is not making any sense. You should provide `unique id` to your `message_box` and then use it, like
 `$(id_of_message_box).find('.likepng, .unlikepng').remove()`

or as I can see from your code:

```
   var $parent = $this.parent().parent();
       $parent.find('.likepng, .unlikepng').remove();
```

It means you should use `$this` in your function instead of `$(this)`

Comment: I know it will not remove sir , i just want see it in html alert and then remove it , but it keep giving me undefined and not worked in the alert .

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Yes i tried your updated but no luck . didnt remove anything .

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parents parent of your $(this) like:

```
var likeholder;

likeholder = $(this).parent().parent();
```

However this is generally ill advised. You'll have a jquery object though.

Let me know how you get on

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need sibling of parent;

```
alert( $this.closest(".like").parent().find(".unlikescore").html()); 
alert ($this.closest('.like').siblings('.unlikepng').html()) ;
```

working [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anilk/q0p4h8nz/)

Comment: Both i got undefined :(

Comment: these seems to be ok to me, create a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/anilk/q0p4h8nz/.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select the parent of a parent of an element you try this:

```
$(document).on ("click", ".deletepng", function () {


     alert( $($(this).parent()).parent().html());

 });
```

Since you can only execute the parent() method on Jquery Objects.
Here's an example unrelated to your code. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pa7n8c0y/).